# Create From/To date columns based on changelog

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

Brief recap of my current situation:
I am looking to combine two separate log files, in order to get the value of one log at the time of another.

I have two tables

1. Price adjustments made
2. Conversion factor adjustments

In order to calculate a given price, in a uniform UOM (Unit of measure) we use the conversion factor as a multiplier

So for instance 1box (Conversion factor) * 200 (Price) = 100pcs (Conversion factor) * 2(Price)

Both price and conversion factor fields in our data has logs on them that looks something like this

```
     Date      Part_No   Supplier_Id   Old_Value   New_Value  
 ------------ --------- ------------- ----------- ----------- 
  11-09-2019   A         B                     1           5  
  19-09-2019   A         B                     5           1
```

The column named LOG_ID is a unique integer since multiple changes can be made on the same day

I am looking to convert the table into something I can join together using a from/to date

So my desired output would be something like below (Please note that the first row has a static From_Date, and the last row has currentdate as To_Date

```
  Part_No   Supplier_Id   From_Date     To_Date     Value  
 --------- ------------- ------------ ------------ ------- 
  A         B             01-03-2010   10-09-2019       1  
  A         B             11-09-2019   18-09-2019       5  
  A         B             19-09-2019   23-10-2020       1
```

I believe that a pivot function combined with a loop is required, but I cannot quite figure out how to combine the two to identify changes made before today, all the way down to an end date.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the previous answer to this question I have come this far

```
SELECT
    Part_No,
    Supplier_Id,
    Date AS From_Date,
    ISNULL(DATEADD(dd,-1,lead(Date) OVER (PARTITION BY Part_No, Supplier_Id ORDER BY Date)),Date) AS To_date,
    New_Value

FROM
    data_Table
```

This results in the following output

```
    Part_No     Supplier_Id   From_Date     To_date     New_Value  
 ------------- ------------- ------------ ------------ ----------- 
  1032515-001          5277   11-09-2019   18-09-2019           5  
  1032515-001          5277   19-09-2019   19-09-2019           1
```

Unfourtunately this is not quite what I am looking for, as explained in my original question. The table below indicates my desired output:

```
  Part_No   Supplier_Id   From_Date     To_Date     Value  
 --------- ------------- ------------ ------------ ------- 
  A         B             01-03-2010   10-09-2019       1  
  A         B             11-09-2019   18-09-2019       5  
  A         B             19-09-2019   23-10-2020       1
```

A static first from_date, and current date as a dynamic final to_date

Answer (score 0):

You need to leverage UNPIVOT and then LEAD function to achieve this:

```sql
DECLARE @table table(dateval date,partno char(1), supplierid char(1),
old_value int, new_value int)

insert into @table 
values
  ('2019-09-11','A','B',1,5),  
  ('2019-09-19','A','B',5,1);

select partno, supplierid, dateval as From_Date, 
isnull(dateadd(dd,-1,lead(dateval) over  (partition by partno, supplierid order by dateval)),dateval) as To_date, val
from @table
unpivot 
(
val
for keyv in ([old_value],[new_value])
) as upvt
where keyv = 'old_value'
```

```
+--------+------------+------------+------------+-----+
| partno | supplierid | From_Date  |  To_date   | val |
+--------+------------+------------+------------+-----+
| A      | B          | 2019-09-11 | 2019-09-18 |   1 |
| A      | B          | 2019-09-19 | 2019-09-19 |   5 |
+--------+------------+------------+------------+-----+
```

Comment: This is not quite what I am looking for unfourtunately

Comment: @HenrikPoulsen, how 2019-10-23 coming into the picture ? we dont have that value in test data

Comment: As mentioned in my original post, the last row should always be from the last entry in the log-file, up until current date (At the time of my original post this was 2019-10-23)